# WebSocket deployed on AKS fails to connect

Tags: azure, go, kubernetes, websocket, azure-aks

We have created a websocket server using golang and was tested locally and on docker. We have deployed the server on Azure Kubernetes Services and since then it refuses to create a connection. **We are using Azure Free Subscription**. Here is what we have done.

Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: overseerservice-deployment
  labels:
    app: dexam-overseer
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dexam-overseer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dexam-overseer
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dexam-overseer
          image: eyadzz/dexam_overseer_service:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9999
          env:
            - name: RABBITMQ_HOST
              value: rabbitmq-service
            - name: RABBITMQ_PORT
              value: :5672

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: overseer-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: dexam-overseer
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 9999
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9999
      nodePort: 30008
```

Js connection code:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://20.106.105.25:9999/ws");
    console.log("Attempting Connection...");

    socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log("Successfully Connected");
        socket.send(("1").toString())

    };


    socket.onclose = event => {
        console.log("Socket Closed Connection: ", event);
        socket.send("Client Closed!")
    };

    socket.onerror = error => {
        console.log("Socket Error: ", error);
    };
```

Error message:

[image]

**[Implementation Code](https://github.com/MarwanGalal746/D-Exam-with-Anti-Cheat-System-Backend/tree/Overseer-Service)**

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `nodePort` parameter from your `Service` since it is of type `LoadBalancer`. Also, you should try specifying an `externalIP` in your service that should correspond to an IP address that is accessible from the outside (perhaps 20.106.105.25). You can add this to your service:

```
externalIPs:
  - 20.106.105.25
```

See [these](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips) docs for more details.

Comment: Specifying service type as "LoadBalancer" already gives the service an external ip to use. I have tried editing the Service with your suggestions but did not work

Comment: Can you provide more details of the error you're seeing?

Comment: I don't really know what else to provide, I have posted a screenshot of me trying to connect using a JS code, it says it fails to connect (more like the ip doesnt exist)